# Find the nth term of the given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is $$1^3 + (2^3 +3^3)+(4^3+5^3+6^3)+...$$

i.e., $1^3$, $(2^3 +3^3)$ , $(4^3+5^3+6^3)$ , $(7^3+8^3+9^3+10^3)$ , and so on are the $1^{st}$, $2^{nd}$, $3^{rd}$ and so on terms respectively. ($(4^3+5^3+6^3)$ is the third term). So we need to find the $n^{th}$ term.

So, the first element of every individual term makes a sequence $1, 2, 4, 7...$.  $\therefore$ the first element of each term is $(1+\frac{n(n-1)}2)^3$ and this the last element is $(\frac{n(n-1)}2 + 1 + (n-1))^3$. But I don't understand what to do next.

Comment: Surely you can describe your series more clearly, e.g. by a recurrence relation. As it is, I find it hard to find out how your series is actually defined. Could you describe the underlying sequence for instance?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence of consecutive integers beginning with one more than the $(n-1)$th triangular number and ending with $(n-1)$ more than the first term. This sequence has $n$ terms. If you take the terms of this sequence, cube them, and add them together, you get the $n$th term of the sequence that you want, which you can call $T_n$.

The $(n-1)$th triangular number is $\frac{n^2-n}2$. One more than that is $\frac{n^2-n+2}{2}$. And $(n-1)$ more than the latter is $\frac{n^2-n+2}{2} + (n-1) = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$.

Therefore $T_n$ can be computed as the difference between $C(\frac{n^2+n}{2})$ and $C(\frac{n^2-n}{2})$, where $C(m)$ represents the sum of consecutive cubes from $1$ to $m$, i.e.

$$T_n = \sum_{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}k^3 = C(\frac{n^2+n}{2}) - C(\frac{n^2-n}{2})$$

Now $C(m) = \frac 14m^2(m+1)^2$ (the sum of the cubes of the first $m$ positive integers is the square of the sum of the first $m$ positive integers, which is also the square of the $m$th triangular number - a standard result which is a particular case of the general Faulhaber's formula).

Hence,

$$\begin{align}T_n &= \frac 14 \left(\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}+1\right)^2 - \left(\frac{n^2-n}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{n^2-n}{2}+1\right)^2 \right) \\&= \frac 18n^3(n^2+1)(n^2+3)\end{align}$$

The final simplification is tedious by hand, but an online computer algebra system makes it trivial. You can verify the formula works for the first few terms, e.g. $T_1 = 1, T_2 = 35, T_3 = 405$ and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand you correctly for I am a little bit confused about your notation. I guess that by the first term of the sequence you mean $1^3$ and $(2^3 + 3^3)$ is the second term, $(4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3)$ is the third term and so on. If this is so, it seems correct that *the firs summand* of the $n$-th term is given by 
$$(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1)^3 \ .$$ 
Since the $n$-th term contains $n$ summands, the *last summand* of the $n$-th term is given by 
$$(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1 + (n-1))^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^3 \ , $$
where we added $(n-1)$ because the first summand is to be raised $(n-1)$ times by $1$ to get the last summand of the $n$-th term (your formula is almost the same for it seems that you used the same logic and only forgot to add $+1$). This expression will serve as a checker after we express the general formula for the $n$-th term.

To describe the $n$-th term should be straightforward now for we know the first summand and the number of steps we have to make to get to the last summand for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The $n$-th term should be 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1 +i)^3 \ . $$ 
The first summand is obviously in accordance with what we know and if we compute the last summand of the above expression we get
$$ (\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1 + n-1)^3 = (\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n)^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2} )^3 \ ,$$ 
which is what we expected.

In case this answer is not what you were looking for, try to specify more carefully what you mean by $n$-th term.

Comment: Yes you got it right, though I thought I had explained the question well enough, but no worries. But why do we only calculate the last element of the nth term?? We actually need the entire nth term??

Comment: We calculate the whole $n$-th term and the expression for it is $\sum_{i=0}^{n−1}(n(n−1)2+1+i)^3$. To calculate the last summand of the $n$-th term is unnecessary and we did it just in order to see whether the expression for the $n$-th term works as we want it to.

Comment: To see that the expression works for all summands and not just the first and the last, you can take arbitrary $n$ and see how it works. Of course it will give us the result only in the form, e.g. $(7^3 + 8^3 + 9^3 + 10^3)$ which I thought is what you are looking for. If you are interested in the actual number you would get in each $n$-th bracket/term, you have to further rewrite the expression. This is what @Deepak is doing in his answer .

Comment: no, what i am asking is that how do we calculate $\sum_{i=0}^{n−1}(n(n−1)2+1+i)^3$ as an expression. the answer is $\frac{1}8 n^3(n^2+1)(n^2+3)$ so how do we get that???

Comment: I see, @Deepak is providing a possible way how to do that.

Comment: yes, but this is a question given in a limited time examination where questions are such that they are possible by hand. @Deepak provides a solution which is much tedious than expected. so surely there must be some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The sum is equal to

$$S_n=1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

The $n^\text{th}$ term in your representation is given as

$$S_{n(n+1)/2}-S_{n(n-1)/2}.$$

The indices are just the partial sums for

$$1+2+...+n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$1+2+...+(n-1)=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: I am not completely sure but it seems that OP's notation is such that $1^3$ is the first term, $(2^3 + 3^3)$ is the second term, $(4^3 + 5^3 + 6^3)$ is the third term and so on.

Comment: I thought that is what I answered ... but it might be that I messed up something :D. I am using the sum of cubes for the representation of the general term, that is why I wrote the $n^\text{th}$ term in your representation is given as ...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that $$a_n= \sum_1^{T(n)} k^3-\sum_1^{T(n-1)} k^3$$

where $T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ are triangular numbers